# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'fault'

Tags: python

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor 
#loading my train dataset into python
train = df[msk]
test = df[~msk]

#factors that will predict the fault
desired_factors = ['Burning rate','Air network','Number of 
users','Circuit Queue','POWER']

#set my model to DecisionTree
model = DecisionTreeRegressor()

#set prediction data to factors that will predict, and set target to 
fault
train_data = train[desired_factors]
test_data = test[desired_factors]
target = train.fault


#fitting model with prediction data and telling it my target
model.fit(train_data, target)

model.predict(test_data.head())
```

> ```
> AttributeError Traceback (most recent call 
> last)
> Cell In [68], line 15
>  13 train_data = train[desired_factors]
>  14 test_data = test[desired_factors]
> ---> 15 target = train.fault
>  18 #fitting model with prediction data and telling it my target
>  19 model.fit(train_data, target)
>  packages\pandas\core\generic.py:5575, in NDFrame.__getattr__(self, 
> name)
> 5568 if (
> 5569     name not in self._internal_names_set
> 5570     and name not in self._metadata
> 5571     and name not in self._accessors
> 5572     and 
> self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
> 5573 ):    5574     return self[name]
> -> 5575 return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
>
> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'fault'
> ```

Comment: Which line gets that error?  Show us the traceback.  As it is, you aren't looking for `fault` anywhere in this code.

Comment: Thats the error of the code above, it says fault has no attribute

Comment: `train` is a dataframe and dataframes have no method or property named `fault`. Is `fault` a column of the dataframe and you mean `train['fault']`? It's not clear what you are trying to do with that line.

Comment: I'm trying to predict the transformer fault using those datasets such as 'Burning rate, Air network, Number of users, Circuit Queue, POWER', datasets are from here excel file https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/yzyj46xpmy/4    I want to develop a code that could predict a transformer fault using those datasets

Comment: where is `dataframe.fault` from?